# react native camera Gradle sync failed: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to install `react-native-camera`.

I did `npm install react-native-camera` `react-native link react-native-camera`.

It gives me the error saying `Gradle sync failed: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container`.

I tried manual link too as stated in the documentation till step 6 where I added

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

I used `exifinterface` versions, e.g. 27.+ instead of 25.+

I have `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip` as distributionUrl and `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`

I dont know what am I missing. When I open my android studio it gives me error `Gradle sync failed: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container`

And when I run `react-native run-android` on my phone it gives me error saying `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cameramanager.aspect')`

Can anyone help me what am I missing here ??

Here is my gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your whole `build.gradle` ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout Updated the question with gradle

Comment: What is your version of `gradle-wrapper.properties` ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip` I think this is what you are talking about

Answer (score 4):

You could try to upgrade your gradle (android\build.gradle) to this version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

to do so you would also need to upgrade the `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

This solved a similar problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, this Worked , Fine, Solved My Problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `gradle-wrapper` distribution url to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Did you try changing that on both the build.gradle of the dependency **and** the project ? I stumbled upon the same issue with my project, and this fixed it